# What is the simplest way to approach this integral problem? To me, this problem seemed to necessitate some kind of gimmick.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, problem-solving

[image]

How can I tackle this problem with as few abstract ideas as possible when attempting to 'purely' integrate from left to right? I've tried a few different versions of this term, but I'm not sure how to get into an answer. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: First thing I would try is the substitution $u=t+\frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: @Paul: I tried, but the left-hand side has a cubic expression, which complicates the calculation and prevents variable substitution into an integrable form.

Comment: Apply the product rule:
$$[e^{g(t)}f(t)]’ = e^{g(t)}[ g’(t)f(t)+f’(t)]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a bit of manipulation and you have the answer.
Split the integral this way.
$\int(t+1-\frac{1}{t}).e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}}+ \int(1-\frac{1}{t^2}).e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}}$
Now right side easily evaluates to $e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}}$.
For the left the side multiply and divide it by $t$ and write it as
$t(\frac{1}{t} +  1- \frac{1}{t^2})$
.
Then the left integral becoems
$\int e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}}dt + \int t(1-\frac {1}{t^2})e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}}dt$.
Now here in the right side integral take $t$ as the 1st and the rest as the 2nd function(and using by parts integration).So the right integral on integrating becomes
$t.e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}}$$- \int e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}}.dt$ which cancels the left most term of the integral hence we finally obtain the integral as
$(t+1).e^{t+ \frac{1}{t}} + C$

Comment: Due to the time difference, I did not respond to the preceding comment right away, but I am writing to thank you today. Is there any way to make this type of problem more accessible? At first glance, I'm unsure how to solve it.

Comment: Are you kinda like asking what must done to solve any such problem most of the time or make it  look easier.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly as you say.

Comment: The question can have variety of answers.I was also not sure during taking $t + 1/t$ as a substitute as function in  the front of e was not very easily simplified.But you know the when  integrals like these where we have a function in front e and also the power of e is also looking to make some relation , then you kinda like stop thinking about other techniques. Because 99% percent of integrals of this forms either include by parts integration or putting the differential of power of e in the form of the front function.This question was a combo of both.This was the idea which kept me following.

Comment: Although it took a while for me to manipulate I was kinda like convinced that it  must be something  to do with the power of e. And sometimes it's also the practice of similar problems which make you realise what could be done.